# Node JS OR Express JS HTTP GET Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using express.js and I need to make a call to HTTP GET request ,to fetch JSON data .Please suggest me some good node js/express js modules/lib to perform get/post request .

Answer (score 2):

Node.js provides an extremely simple API for this functionality in the form of `http.request`.

```
var http = require('http');

//The url we want is: 'www.random.com/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
var options = {
  host: 'www.random.com',
  path: '/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
};

callback = function(response) {
  var str = '';

  //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
  });
}

http.request(options, callback).end();
```

[Here](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request) I attach some more examples with POST and custom headers. If you don't need special things, I'd stick to the native code.

Besides, [Request](https://github.com/request/request), [Superagent](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/) or [Requestify](http://ranm8.github.io/requestify/) are pretty good libraries to use.

Answer (score 2):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile('./test.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.send({error: err});
        }
        res.send(data);
    })
});
var server = app.listen(3001, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening port 3001');
});
```